# Jquery not working from Google CND

Tags: jquery, cdn

I just started creating a html file and wanted to use jquery. When I use the jquery from my local machine like this, it works fine.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But when I try to use this, it does not work

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am not able to use any jquery functions when I load the script like this.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Btw, my html file is on the local machine in drive C:/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your url is incomplete. I believe they leave off the http to show that you can use either http or https, because if you're on a server you don't need it. You only need to add it in if you're running off your file system.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The url does work without http, as long as you aren't trying to use it locally, which he is in this case.

Comment: @KevinB Which he's trying to do.

Comment: Yup that fixes it. Thanks. I was copying it straight off here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. They should atleast mention that we need to put a http.

Answer (score 14):

Since the HTML file is on your local machine, I'm guessing you're viewing it using the `file://` protocol.  Since you've omitted the protocol from your `<script>` tag's `src` attribute, it will also use the `file://` protocol and fail.

I'd suggest hosting the site using a simple webserver running on localhost.  There are a few other oddities when using file:// that might cause you trouble.