# How to display INPUT TYPE on Selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I know its a simple but i tried many solutions but i failed. I have a form on which I use `<select>` tag in `<option>` i use two values `coo` and `uh` i want that when user select uh then it display an extra `input type` field.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
<script>

$('#s_designation').on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "uh") {
        $("#uh").show()
    }
    else {
        $("#uh").hide()
    }
});
</script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<label for="db">Choose type</label>
<select name="s_designation" id="s_designation">

   <option value="coo">Chief Operating Officer</option>
   <option value="uh">Unit Head</option>
</select>

<div id="uh" style="display:none;">
<label for="specify">Specify</label>
<input type="text" name="specify" placeholder="Specify Designation"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is failing?

Comment: my code does not show my extra input field when i click on `uh`

Comment: try putting the code in a `$(document).ready()`. http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/f4pu6uce/ it looks ok.

Comment: your code is working fin, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/m5n6v8as/

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan its not working on my.php file

Comment: @dpanshu its not working when i run it in my browser

Comment: have you included jQuery library?

Comment: @dpanshu in my question i post my whole code. can you please tell me which library is need to include. I am new in jquery

Comment: your library file is incorrect. Check my answer

Comment: Your comment syntax inside the script tag is not what you want. You need to use `/*comment*/` or `//comment` style comments

Comment: Its not working, because your jQuery code is executing before your html document loads. so use `$(document).ready` or place your code before end of the body tag.

Comment: @Srinu can you please post it as answer with code. I am new in Jquery. I cant understand how it do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `jQuery` code is executing before the document loads, which means the `select` element is not visible to `jQuery`, and `jQuery` won't throws error if it didn't find any given element.

use the `$(document).ready` like the following, it will load your code after document loads:

```
<head>
-------
-------
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s_designation').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="uh") {
    $("#uh").show()
    }
    else {
    $("#uh").hide()
    }
  });
});
</script>
-------
</head>
```

if you want to execute jQuery code after page loading

you simply place your jQuery code before `</body>` tag like the following:

```
<body>
-------
-------


<script>

  $('#s_designation').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="uh") {
    $("#uh").show()
    }
    else {
    $("#uh").hide()
    }
  });

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code and it works fine:

`Link:`https://jsfiddle.net/g95pyqw6/

Edit: But that could be because of JSfiddle.
Try to uncomment the first line of Javascript, that should help! :-)

I hope I could help you out. If you need more help, feel free to write a comment :-)

Comment: Its not my browser issue. Coz jquery calender is working fine. but this code have  problem

Comment: When i uncomment first line it Dream Viewer show error

Comment: Now you got my attention. What does DreamViewer tell you? (Am now opening up my DreamViewer)

Comment: Thank You so much Felix. I fix my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

here your Working code (checked on my local machine) answer is here for your problem [Jquery not working from Google CND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279450/jquery-not-working-from-google-cnd#answer-15279479)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
    <script>
    $(function() {
          $('#s_designation').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="uh"){
        $("#uh").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#uh").hide()
        }
    });});
        </script>

    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <label for="db">Choose type</label>
    <select name="s_designation" id="s_designation">

       <option value="coo">Chief Operating Officer</option>
       <option value="uh">Unit Head</option>
    </select>

    <div id="uh" style="display:none;">
    <label for="specify">Specify</label>
    <input type="text" name="specify" placeholder="Specify Designation"/>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your code you have commented the `$(function()` line :

> You are also missing the required jquery library files

Please add this to your html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0mqze5ny/

```
$(function () {
    $('#s_designation').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "uh") {
            $("#uh").show()
        } else {
            $("#uh").hide()
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: can you explain the use of that?